# Notepad++: how to bind Ctrl-e to go to end of line

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

In Notepad++, how do you to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> move the cursor to the end of the line?

Folks coming from unix/linux would find this useful, as it is a classic key combination found in apps like emacs and bash.

Comment: There's a key on your keyboard that says "END".  How about that?

Comment: My question is trying to find a way to make Ctl-E jump to end-of-line in notepad++.  This is so that I dont have to memorize new shortcuts...  also the END is positioned at the far end of the keyboard so its very cumbersome to reach for it

Comment: @RickS I'm typing `End` a lot, and I'd like to not lift a hand off the main keys all the time.  I appreciate this question, and it's a shame that it was downvoted despite being well-formed and directly asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In notepad++ go to Settings-->Shortcut Mapper...
Choose the Scintilla button at the top.

`Map the name SCI_LINEENDWRAP`

[image]

Select this item and click the Modify button.

Check the Ctrl checkbox and find 'E' in the drop down

Click the Apply button and then the Add button.

That part's a little tricky but you'll get it.

Enjoy your new mapping.

Comment: ty @RickS so much!! Bonus! It can 'add' the binding, so that both EOF and ctrl-E will work ! So when my keyboard has an EOL all is well and so it is when I don't. I added on SCI_HOME ctrl-shift-E so that I have a 'toggle' for beginning of line / end of line. (On normal CLI mode we would use ctrl-A for start of line, but since that selects all on a 2D GUI app, I didn't want that.)